# I'm writing a javafx custom LoginModule and receive the below AccessControlException concerning javafx permissions. Is this a policy file issue?

Tags: java, policy, jaas

Windows 10 - cmd prompt:
I've created a simple JavaFX application that accepts a username and pw. When I attempt to run the code I get the below error message. 
All that should be happening initially is a gui gets loaded. When I run this code without security.manager the gui loads and operates correctly, albeit a LoginContext cannot be instantiated. But even when running with security.manager the LoginContext would not be instantiated until the form fields have data inputted and the enter key is pressed. At this early stage the LoginContext or LoginModule should not be playing any role in this problem....I think.

```
Cmd prompt:\TestLogin>java -classpath LoginMain.jar;TestLoginModule.jar 
-Djava.security.manager 
-Djava.security.policy==jaasPolicy.policy 
-Djava.security.auth.login.config==jaasConfig.config 
com.login.LoginGui

/* Login configuration file */
DbLogin {
  com.login.security.TestLoginModule required debug=true;
};


/* policy file */
grant codebase "file:./TestLoginModule.jar" {
    permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "modifyPrincipals";
};

grant codebase "file:./LoginMain.jar" {
   permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "createLoginContext.TestLoginModule";
};

grant codebase "file:./LoginMain.jar" {
   permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "createLoginContext.other";
};



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            /* testing Thread class vs Javafx thread */
            //Thread t = new Thread(()->{

            System.out.println("launching javafx");

            launch(args);
            /*
                System.out.println("Before sleep");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }catch(InterruptedException ex) {

                }
                System.out.println("after sleep");
            });

            t.start();
            */
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("LoginGui.main -> error -> " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javafx.verbose" "read")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Boolean.getBoolean(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:241)
        ... 5 more
```

If I need to include in my policy file the following permission, java.util.PropertyPermission "javafx.verbose" "read", or some form of it. What's the correct syntax? Where and how in policy do I set this permission?

I'm feeling my way through this process, building custom LoginModules, counting on the error messages to lead me to the promise land.

Answer (score 0):

```
grant codeBase "file:javafx-sdk-11/lib/javafx.base.jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
grant codeBase "file:javafx-sdk-11/lib/javafx.controls.jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
grant codeBase "file:javafx-sdk-11/lib/javafx.fxml.jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
grant codeBase "file:javafx-sdk-11/lib/javafx.graphics.jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
grant codeBase "file:javafx-sdk-11/lib/javafx.media.jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
grant codeBase "file:javafx-sdk-11/lib/javafx.swing.jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
grant codeBase "file:javafx-sdk-11/lib/javafx.web.jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

This should solve your problem
. A good guide to you is check out the bugs.openjdk.java.net 
They have a collection of solved & unsolved bugs.^^